# Android: Can we set more than one tag at a time for the Grid-view item?

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

Can we set more than a tag for a grid-view cell item.
For example can we set "mobile","phone","communication" tags for the single item.
i have tried getting the array of items but its not working.
Any Ideas?

Comment: "not working" is a completely useless description of your symptoms. The tag on a `View` can be any object, such as an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you for your response,sorry i have written setting instead of getting.how can get the tag from the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a `View` named `v`, to associate an `ArrayList<String>` named `a` with `v` as its tag, call `v.setTag(a)`.

Given a `View` named `v`, to retrieve an `ArrayList<String>` from `v` as its tag, call `(ArrayList<String>)v.getTag()`.